# Angular NG-Repeat Only only display some columns

Tags: angularjs

I have an object that I get from an API call that has a lot of data in it that I don't necessarily need. How do i set up my ng-repeat to only show the columns that I want.

For example each row has 13 columns and I only want column 1,3,11. the object is not keyed so I cant just do

```
 <td> {{a.blah}}</td>
 <td> {{a.foo}} </td>
```

here is my current ng-repeat. I know It has to be something about filtering on the index.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in playerInfoBody track by $index">
                <td ng-repeat="a in d track by $index">
                    {{a}}
                </td>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in playerInfoBody track by $index">
            <td ng-repeat="a in d track by $index" ng-if="[1,3,11].indexOf($index) > -1">
                {{a}}
            </td>
```

Comment: where does `contains()` come from?

Comment: your right. I use js and c# and mixed this one up :)

Comment: Lovely, I learn more about the wonderful world of Angular each day!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to display the items according the 'mod' function
Although it's not the best way in doing so, preferred best to only return the items that are valid to show from the API.

> mod = Returns the remainder after number is divided by divisor. The
>   result has the same sign as divisor.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in playerInfoBody track by $index">
    <td ng-repeat="a in d" ng-show='$index % 1 == 0 || $index % 3 == 0 || $index % 11 == 0'>
        {{a}}
    </td>
</tr>
```